# Mapping Property of $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Consider the map $f(z)=\dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$.

What is the image of Circle with radius $ r $ under $f$

I got $x=\dfrac{r^2 -1 }{r^2 -2r\cos(\theta) +1} $ and $y=\dfrac{-2r\sin(\theta)}{r^2 -2r\cos(\theta) +1}$.

I don't know what to do further.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the circle $\mathcal C$ is centered at the origin. Then $\mathcal C$ is symmetric wrt the imaginary axis, therefore $f(\mathcal C)$ is symmetric wrt the image of the imaginary axis, which is the real axis. If $r = 1$, $f(\mathcal C)$ goes through $0$ and $\infty$, therefore it's the imaginary axis. Otherwise $f(\mathcal C)$ is the circle for which $[f(-i r), f(i r)]$ is a diameter.

Comment: How did you get that $f(\mathcal C)$ is symmetric wrt Imaginary axis?

Comment: Wrt the *image* of the imaginary axis. In this case, you can directly verify that $f$ takes a pair of points $\pm a + i b$ to complex conjugates. More generally, a Mobius transform maps points which are conjugate wrt a generalized circle to points which are conjugate wrt the image of that generalized circle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=w=u+iv$. 
$w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ This implies $z=\frac{i(1+w)}{1-w}$. 
Image of $|z|\le r$ and if $r=1$ then$|1+w|\le|1-w|$ Putting $w=u+iv$ in above equation and solving, we get $u
\gt 0$.Hence f map unit circle to {$u+iv:u$$\gt$ 0} And for $r\gt 1$ same way we get
{$u+iv:$$(u-1)^2+v^2\gt 0$}

Comment: $u > 0$ is probably a typo for $u < 0$. Note that what you mean is the unit disk, not the unit circle. And surely the region must depend on $r$ if $r > 1$.